# Visual Studio 2010 SQL Database Project Command-Line Schema Compare

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-project

I use SQL 2008 Database Project to keep track of all my database changes and easilly update databases by running schema compares on them.

A bad thing is that I need to have VS2010 on the machine I want to perform the schema compare.

Currently I've been able to open a door on the remote servers and connect to them, executing the schema comprare on my machine but it would be great if I could execute everything right on the destination server.

Is there a way to perform a schema compare using nothing but the generated DB Project schemas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why is it a bad thing that you have SQL2008 databases and work with VS2010. I do it every day. But if you just want to compare two DB schemas (meaning .dbschema files).here is an article on how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435.aspx#comparewithvsdbcmd

Comment: It's not actually bad, but I don't usually have VS2010 on my production machines and updating those databases can be a pain if I can't establish a connection between my connection and the production SQL instance.
Basically I would prefer to update the production schema by command line execution for example...

This is just me throwing some thoughts out... :)

Comment: that's a different story. For production I don't even trust schema compare :)  I get a list of changes from the sourcecode (in this case TFS) and automatically create deployment scripts for each object. It sounds like a lot of work but it's mostly automated so not a big deal. and this way I know exactly what's going into prod and have a rollback script in case things go wrong.

Comment: I use schema compare with caution. I uncheck a lot of things and then copy/paste it to SSMS to validate the script but as I have a staging environment, most of the problems are detected on the several staging updates I do before releasing to production.
So basically when I run it to production rarely something unexpected occurs.

Comment: Creating the schema changes by hand is just not doable for me... On each sprint I usually have a lot of changes, really a lot, and on top of that my projects are on top of a distributed platform of several WCF Services each having their own database so it would be insane to update all my databases by hand.

My rollback script is a backup right after putting the sites offline and just before starting the update process! :)